# Why can't I install the software for my G9X on my Windows 8.1 machine?

Tags: canon, software, troubleshooting, windows, powershot

Just received my lovely silver G9x and it's a thrill to behold.

I have configured it to wirelessly send photos to both my phone and to Google Drive. That works like a purring charm.

But I have really struggled with getting it to connect to my home computer.

I have done the following:

- Download Digital Camera Software 6.0 [Windows] from [Canon's webste](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/digital_compact/powershot_g_series/powershot_g9_x.aspx?type=download&language=&os=WINDOWS%207%20(64-bit))
- Unzipped the files and the installation failed twice (for some reason not all files were created).
- After uninstalling and restarting the machine, I was able to install, and, as per the [G9x manual instructions](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300021418/02/PowerShot_G9_X_Camera_User_Guide_EN.pdf) on how to install this (pp. 138-139), I can see the wi-fi connection setup .exe. When I double-click this, the following error is presented:

`canon utilities wireless camera connection setting has stopped working`

I have googled this error to death and found nothing.

My laptop is running Windows 8.1.

This seems like an issue with that download, the Digital Camera Software 6.0, as I just tried on my work computer and had an issue (admittedly, a different issue, how annoying).
Please help!

Thank you.

Edit: according to the Canon site, my laptop does not need any driver updates

Comment: Whether or not the documentation claims 8.1 is supported, 8.1 is buggy at best.  In addition,  Manufacturers of consumer products (such as cameras) are terrible at doing full software QA and regression testing, so their claims of compatibility are often weak.

Answer (score 1):

The link you have posted is to the [Windows 7 version](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/digital_compact/powershot_g_series/powershot_g9_x.aspx?type=download&language=&os=WINDOWS%207%20(64-bit)) of the file.  Try [this link](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/digital_compact/powershot_g_series/powershot_g9_x.aspx?type=download&language=EN&os=Windows%208.1%20(64-bit)) for Windows 8.1 (x64) version.

Hope it helps!